# Does rerunning your application in android studio restart services?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an android app. It includes an intent service to do some background work. Does rerunning the app from android studio (on a phone) also restart the service? In other words, can I be sure to be using the most recent version of the service?

Comment: It should terminate your process as part of loading in a fresh APK. I have not experimented much with the scenario where the APK is unchanged, but you run it again from the IDE -- on Eclipse, sometimes this would not terminate your process.

Comment: Yes, each time you deploy your app the new version replaced the old version which subsequently stops all components that were still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a printout in. It came up. The answer is thus: Yes

Answer (score 0):

> Does rerunning the app from android studio (on a phone) also restart the service?

So far I have observed that AS builds a new apk and installs it to the device everytime a Run command is issued. That means killing all processes of your app, replacing the apk (that includes activating receivers, content provider) and starting main activity.

In Eclipse when no changes were made only the main activity was started.

> In other words, can I be sure to be using the most recent version of the service?

Yes, you can.